# Decode json string to struct from response data in Swift

Tags: json, swift, escaping, quotes, backslash

I have a test server written in python which produces json output on single path: '/'

```
import json

from fastapi import FastAPI
from uvicorn import run

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
def main():
    return json.dumps([{
        'name': 'ihor',
        'age': 5
    }])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Then I have my iOS client in SwiftUI and trying to fetch a json from my server and decode it into struct.

Here's the code of api call and decoding:

```
import SwiftUI

class Network: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User] = []
    
    func getUsers() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000")

        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Request error: ", error)
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }

            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))
                        let decodedUsers = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
                        self.users = decodedUsers
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}


struct User: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}
```

And it's called from simple content view

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var network: Network
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
                        Text("All users")
                        .font(.title).bold()
            if network.users.count > 0 {
            Text(network.users.first!.name)
                }
        }
                .onAppear {
                        network.getUsers()
                }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()    .environmentObject(Network())
    }
}
```

After all it's produces the next output:

`"[{\"name\": \"ihor\", \"age\": 5}]" Error decoding:  typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Looks like JSONDecoder cannot handle input with escaped backslashes and quotes at the start and at the end.

Everything works fine once I remove first and last quotes and escaped backslashes:

```
do {
    let rawJsonString = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
                        
    let lowerIndex = rawJsonString.index(rawJsonString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
    let upperIndex = rawJsonString.index(rawJsonString.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
                        
    let jsonString = rawJsonString[lowerIndex..<upperIndex].replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
                        
    print(jsonString)
                        
    let decodedUsers = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: jsonString.data(using:.utf8)!)
    self.users = decodedUsers
} catch let error {
    print("Error decoding: ", error)
}
```

But it's pretty dirty solution and wouldn't work with nested json that have to be escaped with backslashes.

Is there a simple solution to parse JSON like this to struct?

Comment: What did you print exactly as "output"? Are you sending JSON Stringified? Why? Could you print raw data: `print("Data: \(data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())` at the same level of `print(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))`? Else, I would have used: `let decoder = JSONDecoder(); let stringified = try decoder.decode(String.self, from: data);  let users = try decoder.decode([User].self, from: Data(stringified.utf8))`

Comment: @darencorp your client code seems fine to me. In your python code `json.dumps` converts your json into a `String`, is that why `Swift` is havinng trouble decoding it as it expects an `Array` but finds a `String`? Could you try returning the json object directly without `json.dumps`?

Comment: @Larme solution that you suggested is working pretty well. Thank you for this one. Please tell me if I understood it right: I got my response from server and at first step it must be decoded from primitive string into JSON string using interface **String.self** and only then it could be decoded into **Array** by using dedicated interface? If so, could you please write an answer below, I would like to select it as a proper solution?

Comment: If you can modify the php part, please modify it, make it easier, and more common as said by @justintime. I don't know about PHP, so I can't help you with that part.

Comment: @justintime Actually JSON format is a string (such as YAML and XML), and then you can decode it to your data structure such as map, array, object etc. As Larme suggested it has to be converted to proper String format and only then it could be decoded into array.